# Recall a Variable in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, variables

I have a question, I have a panda dataframe with all these attributes:

bdo_0_5 bdo_5_15 bdo_15_30 bdo_30_60 bdo_60_100 bdo_100_20 cec_0_5 cec_5_15 cec_15_30 cec_30_60 cec_60_100 cec_100_20 n_0_5 n_5_15 n_15_30 n_30_60 n_60_100 n_100_200 ocd_0_5 ocd_5_15 ocd_15_30 ocd_30_60 ocd_60_100 ocd_100_20 ph_0_5 ph_5_15 ph_15_30 ph_30_60 ph_60_100 ph_100_200 soc_0_5 soc_5_15 soc_15_30 soc_30_60 soc_60_100 soc_100_20

the variable are bdo, cec, n, ocd, ph and soc but i have their value for differents depths (0-5cm, 5-15cm, 15-30cm, 30-60cm, 60-100cm, 100-200cm).

As you can see every attributes name is composed by: ["variable name"*"upper dept"*"lower dept"]

I'm doing a loop and i need to recall all the variables:

```
name = ["ph", "cec", "bdo", "n", "soc", "ocd"]
udg = [0, 5, 15, 30, 60, 100]
ldg = [5, 15, 30, 60, 100, 200]

for n in name:
    for u, l in zip(udg, ldg):
        print(**n_u_l**)
```

I need this for a much more complicated problem but I would like to recall my variabe using only the counters n, l, u, is it possible. How can i do it?

Full code:

```
for n in name:
    for u, l in zip(udg, ldg):
        if upper_dept<=u & lower_dept>=l:
            value = value + ((l-u)*n_u_l)
        elif upper_dept>u & lower_dept>=l : 
            value = value + ((l-upper_dept)*var)
        elif upper_dept<=u & lower_dept<l:
            value = value + ((lower_dept-l)*var)
        else:
            value = value
```

var is the variable that i want to recall

Answer (score 1):

```
name = ["ph", "cec", "bdo", "n", "soc", "ocd"]
udg = ["0", "5", "15", "30", "60", "100"]
ldg = ["5", "15", "30","60", "100", "200"]

for n in name:
    for u, l in zip(udg, ldg):
        print(n + "_" + u + "_" + l)
```

Assuming your in python you might want this.
So by transforming to strings you can concacenate them like that.
And you will have a string matching the request to send to your data requester.

Comment: Thanks, But i have a problem in the complete code i have to use l and u as numbers. I will edit the question and put the complete code

Comment: Can't you then just use `(n + "_" + str(u) + "_" + str(l))`

Comment: @user19077881 yes you can didnt thought of that at first

Comment: @MatteoDalleVaglie then you should use str(u) as proposed by the other comment